# Looking for records in Dumfriesshire pre 1841

Tags: 19th-century, scotland

Specifically for Thomas Kerr, possibly from Sanquar born around 1806 though listed in one census as being born around 1811.
I've searched on Ancestry and Scotland's People but can't find a birth date or the names of either parent. The same goes for his wife Lillias (Lilleus) Granger possibly from Strathaven born 1804, no birthdate and no parents. They married in 1830 but no documents list parents of either.

There is an 1807 listing for a Thomas Kerr born to a James Kerr in Dumfries but not sure if he's the same.

Answer (score 4):

The Scotlandspeople site only holds [parish registers](https://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk/guides/church-registers) for the Church of Scotland, the Roman Catholic Church in Scotland, and a few other Presbyterian churches.

The records of many other denominations are held by [National Records of Scotland](https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/research/guides/old-parish-registers/list-of-old-parish-registers), but these are not yet available to search online and you either need to visit their office in Edinburgh, or hire someone to visit on your behalf.

You should be aware that the history of the protestant church in Scotland is not a straightforward one, and that locating the church records for a particular group can also sometimes be a non-trivial exercise!

[image: Scottish Church Timeline]

- Image source [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Christianity_in_Scotland#/media/File:Churches_of_Scotland_timeline.png)

The Genuki page on [Church Records in Scotland](http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/sct/ChurchRecords) includes further links that you might find useful.

---

In the case of Thomas Kerr and his wife Lillias, the first step would be to try and identify which church they would have attended. It's possible that you may find this from their marriage certificate.

A search on [FamilySearch](https://www.familysearch.org/) shows a number of children named Thomas Kerr baptised in Dumfriesshire between 1806 and 1811.

As one last complication, it is also worth remembering that the baptism might have occurred some years after the birth.